# Segmentation fault in two browser plugins with identical global variables

Tags: c++, plugins, browser, global-variables

I remember that a browser plugin in a major open source browser have had a crash because two plugins used the same global variable names.

I would like to review this case, to see which measures did they use to make sure this wouldn't happen again, and more importantly how did they debug that out. Those methods might be useful for us.

Alas, my google-fu is failing me. Can someone provide a reference?

(I think it was in the moonshine browser plugin, but I'm not sure).

Answer (score 2):

It's probably this [incident](http://neugierig.org/software/chromium/notes/2011/01/plugin-conflict.html).

Comment: Jeez... the Netscape browser plugin API may have sounded like a good idea in 1995, but it has undeniably evolved into one of the worst nightmares of browser and internet security.